# Scheduled Task Crashing At Random Points During .Net Program Execution Only with Release Build (Debug Build Works Fine)

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks

I have created a scheduled task to run a .net program with the "Run whether user is logged on or not" option checked. The Task is completing before the program finishes. No exceptions are being thrown, and the task will finish at different points during the .net programs execution (it gets further along sometimes but never finishes, this is based off of my logs).

This is only occurring when I build to Release. If I use the Debug exe to run the program it works with out a problem. If the "Run only when user is logged on" option is chosen it works correctly. If the program is run manually it also works correctly.

I have tried changing the user account that runs the task to SYSTEM, which sometimes allows the program to get further along, before it crashed much earlier on. I have tired unchecking the "Stop if the computer ceases to be idle" flag.

Comment: Perhaps it's being garbage collected? GC is behaving differently in Release builds.

Comment: There are too many possibilities not addressed in the question... Does it complete correctly if you just run it from the command line? Is the scheduled task running as you or a different user? Does that user have permissions to write wherever you are expecting exception logs to be written? Are any of the other scheduled task rules relevant (for example, *but not limited to*: if this is a long running process, and the Scheduled Task has been told to kill it after an hour). You say *it crashed earlier on*: if it's crashing, an exception's thrown: logging these to same log or somewhere different?

Comment: It does work when I run it from the command line. I think I've solved this though, I was spinning up threads to run certain UI pieces that needed a STA ApartmentState thread. Since these aren't needed for the Scheduled Task I added logic to not spin up these threads if the task task is scheduled. Still not 100% what was happening, but I believe the threads I was spinning up were causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved this, I was spinning up threads to run certain UI pieces that needed a STA ApartmentState thread. Since these aren't needed for the Scheduled Task I added logic to not spin up these threads if it is running as a scheduled task. Still not 100% what was happening, but I believe the threads I was spinning up were causing the issue.